# jQuery get values when use load for call other page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-load

I use jQuery **load** for call one script and this script works perfectly, buy i want get response when use load inside this function, i put my example :

```
<script>
function insert(id)
{
jQuery("#loader").load("edit.php?insert=ok&id="+id+"");
}
</script>
```

This script call to edit.php for insert informations in a simple text document, the case it´s this script return some values and i want get this values, i put the php script :

**edit.php**

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['insert']=="ok")
{
if(file_exists("img/".$_REQUEST['id'].""))
{
$result="fail";
}
else
{
fopen("img/".substr($_REQUEST['id'],0,-4).txt."","a");
$result="ok"
}

?>
```

The case it´s how i can get value from **$result** inside function insert(id), because i want get this value inside function for running other things and it´s important for me get inside this function when load and call to this script edit.php, i see some examples but don´t works for me.

**Thank´s in advance for the help, best regards**

Comment: `$result = "ok"` is missing a semi-colon

Comment: Is edit.php complete? There is no output generated. So, the client won't get any content to process.

Comment: Yes i need get response from script and see inside function with jquery by this my question how i can do this

Comment: In General: just print/echo something out. It could be a good idea to build an array, which you can transform to JSON before printing (`echo json_encode($data);`) It can be necessary to set content-type header accordingly, before any output is done (`header('content-type:application/json');`)

Comment: Yes i see some examples but i don´t know how do in my case for use json, by this send my questions, thank´s